# Simple way to display website Total Users value from GA4 inside a static website html page

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have setup GA4 through GTM on my website and it displays Users count value for the past 7 days on the default page in Google Analytics.

My goal is to display a similar metric **in my website html page** which would track the total visitors to my website in the past 3 months.

Suggestions I have encountered is to either
i) pull that already calculated GA Users value or
ii) create a custom metric which would track total users to my website.

I am struggling how to piece it all together.

For example,

- how do I create a Tag inside GTM to reference GA4 metric and setup a proper trigger?
- how do I then display the value inside my static website html  element? Ie. should I be pulling it from the data layer or referencing it from gtag..

Any pointers highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

- Either you do these steps:

#### 1. Fetching Data from Google Analytics (GA4):

Google Analytics has an API you can use to pull data from your account, including user counts.

##### Steps:

1. Set up and authenticate with the [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart).
2. Make an API request to fetch the total users for the past 3 months.

#### 2. Displaying the fetched data on your static HTML website:

Once you've got the data from GA4, you can display it on your website.

- Or you go for customized way

**Customized method**
However, implementing your goal using custom event and GTM involves multiple steps. Let's break it down:

Working with Google Tag Manager (GTM) to obtain the total users from Google Analytics (GA) requires a multi-step approach. GTM serves as an intermediary tool to manage and deploy tracking code snippets (tags) without having to modify the website code directly.

Here's a step-by-step guide on how to connect GTM to Google Analytics and obtain the total users:

#### 1. Setup Google Tag Manager:

1. **Create a GTM Account and Container**: Go to the [Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/) website and sign in. Create an account for your company or website and then create a container for your specific website.
2. **Install GTM Code**: Once you create a container, GTM will provide you with a code snippet. This code needs to be added to every page on your website. Typically, this involves adding one piece of code high in the `<head>` and another immediately after the opening `<body>` tag.

#### 2. Link Google Analytics (GA4) to GTM:

1. **Create a New Tag**: Within your GTM container, click on “New Tag”.
2. **Tag Configuration**: Choose the tag type as "GA4 Configuration" (since September 2023 this tag's name has chaged in GA4).
3. **Enter Measurement ID**: You will need to provide your GA4 Measurement ID (e.g., `G-XXXXXXXXXX`). This ID can be found in your GA4 account in your analytics.google account  under "Property > Data Streams."
4. **Triggering**: Choose the triggering event for this tag. For basic page view tracking, you would select the "All Pages" trigger.
5. **Save and Publish**: Save the tag and then publish the changes to your container. Once published, the GA4 tracking will be live on your website.

This way you are triggering the tag, on every page. So, an event is getting triggered and using a backend-code like Java, python or node.js etc you can read all the events within the last 3 months or whatever and simply count them.

Comment: thank you kindly for the detailed steps! however, I was hoping to get away with just running JS code inside the static html page without any backend-code. Not sure if there's a way that GTM can be synced with the datalayer inside the html page itself and allow me to simply display the Total Visitors inside a <div> element?

Comment: You can do that but it is not recommended since you need to share your secret key. Plus, using a js code would convert your page to a dynamic  one. I will try to share the js sample code asap.

Comment: @wavemonger check this link there is node.js example https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#node.js_1